# scroll a page up and down and across specific range

Tags: vba, excel

I have a worksheet with multiple command buttons / shapes assigned to macros that my users can click on to perform certain  actions. However, I want this worksheet to look a  bit more "professional" like a dashboard so I would need to be able to show all these buttons on the top left hand side corner of the first page (say in column A).

The problem is that my worksheet is several pages long and when I scroll down, the buttons disappear too as they stay on the first page.

I know I can freeze the first page but it doesn't look right because I have too many buttons to fit in the first couple of rows. For example doesn't look user friendly to freeze the first 10 rows, hence I want to have all these button on the top left hand side corner of the first page.

I've come up with the following code to allow the user to scroll but it doesn't seem to work:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
    Worksheets("dummy").ScrollArea = "B1:AA5000"
End Sub
```

Your help is much appreciated and any questions then please let me know.

Comment: could anybody help with the above please? thanks very much in advance.

Comment: This isn't really something that can be done easily; excel doesn't have an option to have multiple panes side-by-side so that one pane is static while the other can move. As you state - you can split and freeze panes, but if you've already considered that and discarded it I see two options really. 1) Have a worksheet scroll macro that repositions all your buttons each time the worksheet is scrolled so they are effectively stationary or create a userform with the buttons on and show it non-modally; this is essentially a separate window so scrolling of the worksheet shouldn't effect it.

Comment: Thanks Flephal, I would try a worksheet scroll macro but not sure how to write it. If you could advise, that would be greatly appreciated. Thanks

Comment: I'm sorry to be a pain, if you could look into I'd be hugely grateful? Thank you

Comment: I've had a quick look around and tried a few things, but there doesn't appear to easily be a scroll event that can be captured. I think a userform is the way forward for this option...

Comment: Oh ok :(  thanks for trying